# Laravel 4 white screen using eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to pass an array of database entries to a view using Eloquent. I'm new to MVC development. The code is as follows:

*School.php* (model)

```
class School extends Eloquent 
{
 protected $table = 'Schools';
 public $timestamps = false; 
 protected $softDelete = false;

 public function school()   
 {
    return $this->hasOne('School');
 }

}
```

*SchoolController.php* (controller)

```
class SchoolController extends BaseController 
{
    public $restful = true;

    public function getIndex()
    {
        return View::make('schools')
            ->with('schools', School::all()); 
    }
}
```

*schools.blade.php* (View)

```
@extends('layouts.schools')

@section('school-search')

<ul>
@foreach($schools as $school)
    <li>{{ $school->name }}</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
@stop
```

However, I'm getting a white screen of death when I load the page. The view works fine when I comment out the "->with('schools', School::all())" part, so I think it has to do with Laravel failing to access the School object. I've googled/stackoverflowed a bit and can't find anyone with a similar problem.

Thanks!

edit: Some relevant info:
I have had this problem before, where it would whitescreen anything I routed to, however I corrected that by changing app/storage permissions. Changing permissions does not seem to help this whitescreen problem.

Laravel seems to be error reporting just fine. When there is something that doesn't make sense in my code, I get an error.

We are in development environment.

edit:

when I run php artisan serve, it gives an error "This php binary is not version 5.4 or greater" Could this be related?

edit:

I've updated to PHP 5.4. Still whitescreening. Here is the latest in my error log.

```
#0 /var/www/playground/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ServeCommand.php(29): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand->checkPhpVersion()
#1 /var/www/playground/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(108): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand->fire()
#2 /var/www/playground/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php(241): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#3 /var/www/playground/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(96): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#4 /var/www/playground/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(892): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#5 /var/www/playground/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(191): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#6 /var/www/playground/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(121): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#7 /var/www/playground/artisan(59): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#8 {main} [] []
```

Comment: What environment are you running? `php artisan env`. I suspect you're getting a white page due to being in production by default.

Comment: Yes, it says that I am in production environment. I'm pretty new, so I'm not sure how that could be causing the problem? Thanks so much!

Comment: Well you need to properly setup your application. You're getting a white screen due to a 500 error and since you're running as production the error is hidden as a security measure. Start here: http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#environment-configuration

Comment: I've set the environment to 'development' and the whitescreen is still occurring unfortunately. Running php artisan env shows I am in development but the whitescreen is still there.

Sorry, but thank you so much :)

Comment: @user3527834, do you have something on the logs? Check for something suspicious at: `<your-project>/app/storage/logs/`.

Comment: @user3527834 `php artisan serve` depends on the builtin web server of PHP, which only exists in PHP >=5.4. However, PHP 5.3 is **end of life**, and you should upgrade to *at least* 5.4 as soon as you can.

Comment: Thanks so much for all this help. I've upgraded to PHP 5.4. :) This did not fix the problem but was a good update nonetheless.

I am now googling the errors found in app/storage/logs. I am new to Laravel so I'm not able to interpret these errors definitively yet. Nothing coming up.

Will update. Thank you for all this help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class School extends Eloquent 
{
 protected $table = 'Schools';
 public $timestamps = false; 
 protected $softDelete = false;

 public function school()   
 {
    return $this->hasOne('School');
 }

}
```

You have a School object which has a one to one relationship with another school object?  You also haven't defined the foreign key to the relationship

I think that laravel is just recursively loading school object after school object and then running out of memory before it can build an error. You can test this by commenting out the entire school() function and seeing what happens.

Another question can you access you apache error log?

Comment: Oh my goodness! What an idiot error on my part!

Thank you so much. This has corrected the problem.

When I'm a bit more well versed, I hope to pay this forward. :)

Thank you!

Comment: @user3527834 not a problem, I enjoy answering the questions on here :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with your *School.php's* relationship defination.

```
public function school()
{
   return $this->hasOne('School');
}
```

By this you are telling laravel that this model has a `one-to-one` / `one-to-many` relationship with itself and this causes a recursive loop when `School::all()` is called. Once the loop exceeds the max allowed memory size as set in `php.ini`, it will return an empty response. Thats why you are getting a blank screen.

This relationship does not seem logical to me but if the schools are hierarchical, you should change the method name `school()` to something like `parent()` to avoid confusing laravel. Eg..

```
public function parent()
{
   return $this->hasOne('School', 'parent_id');
}
```

Comment: You are correct, sir. I thank you so, so much for this answer!!!! It was ultimately just an idiot error on my part.  

I am sorry to waste this community's time. :(